# using MomentJS with TypeScript - What type does moment() have?

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I am currently converting my project from ES5 to ES6, but I am running into an issue with MomentJS (`version 2.18.1`). The problem is that I have a few variables that are Moment objects, but I cannot call moment() on them.

An example:

```
import * as moment from "moment";

export class DateThingy {

  constructor(private moment) { //What type does this have??
  }

  public getDate(): moment.Moment { 
    return this.moment();
  }
}
```

1) If I set the type of `private moment` to `private moment: moment` WebStorm complains: "*cannot find name 'moment'.*"

2) If I set the type to `private moment: moment.Moment` the object has changed and I cannot call `this.moment()` anymore (it is now an object and does not have a function call on it). Webstorm tells me: "*cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signiture. Type 'Moment' has no campatible call signatures.*"

3) I cannot use MomentStatic anymore, since it is not exported. If I type `private moment: moment.MomentStatic` WebStorm gives me: "*namespace 'moment' does not have an exported member 'MomentStatic'*"

So what typing should I use for this example?

Comment: You say "ES6" in your title, but it appears as though you're actually using TypeScript (from the code and the tags). You should use #2, and there will be a global `moment` you can use, like `getDate(): moment.Moment { return moment(); }`

Comment: Examine `moment.d.ts`. By the way, `moment` is a namespace, not a type.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, you are right. Changed the title. But I don't understand your answer. If I add moment.Moment als typing I get "cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signiture". So what do you mean with a global?

Comment: @torazaburo, that is right. `moment` is also a function (`declare function moment(): moment.Moment`). But I want to know how I can type the variable so that I can call that function on it? (`moment` has a function `()` on it's interface, but I cannot seem to give the variable the type `moment`)

Comment: You're looking for `moment.Moment`.

Comment: @torazaburo, using that results in WebStorm giving me the warning: `cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signiture. Type 'Moment' has no campatible call signatures.`. So I'm guessing thats not it :(
If I check the moment typings, the interface `Moment` does not have any  function signiture like `moment()` or `()`

Comment: Remove the `private moment` from the constructor, and note that in the code I provided I wrote `return moment();`, not `return this.moment();` That's what I mean by global; it's not attached to the class or a `moment` namespace and there is no `Moment` class to instantiate. Just `moment()`.

Comment: You can import and use moment typing import type { Moment } from "moment"

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As [Mike McCaughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/mike-mccaughan) said, the moment object cannot be injected in the constructor. Somehow this was possible with an old version of MomentJS. this could be resolved by removing the constructor property and accessing the global moment object that is included via `import * as moment from "moment"`.

The function `moment()` returns a `Moment` object. This can be typed via `moment.Moment`.

So the code can be rewritten as follows:

```
import * as moment from "moment";

export class DateThingy{

     constructor() {
     }

     public getDate(): moment.Moment { 
        return moment();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

You can import and use moment typing like so:

```js
import moment, { Moment } from "moment";

const timeNow: Moment = moment();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Why does this answer has so little votes ?

Comment: I ask myself that all the time, @NelsonTeixeira

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I agree

Comment: Works if `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` is set in compilerOptions section of tsconfig.json in my Angular project.

Answer (score 22):

Did you tried importing moment without alias?

`import moment from 'moment';`

This worked for me. And typescript compiler won't complain about it.

`const date =  moment().format('YYYYMMDD');`

**Note that this requires a tsconfig update!**

In the TSConfig you need to add the option [allowSyntheticDefaultImports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to allow default imports of libraries that have no default exports.

Example (tsconfig.json):

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: It says; moment has no default export; even tho, it fixed next error: `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof moment' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: @Kunok, you need to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to the tsconfig.json in order to be able to use libraries with no default exports this way in typescript.

Answer (score -1):

I got Error message like this

**Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof moment' has no compatible call signatures.**

My issue was importing with alias

> import * as momentns  from 'moment';

I changed this to

> import moment from 'moment';

solved for me in angular 8(TypeScript 2.4)

Comment: Duplicate answer