# How to use momentjs in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have an [Angular 5 library](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-library-starter-kit) project and I want to use `momentjs` version `2.20.1`.

I followed [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) on how to install for TypeScript and for the most part everything works. When I test my library using `ng test` I have no problems however when I try to package the lib with `npm run build` I get

> Cannot call a namespace ('moment')

when using `import * as moment from 'moment';`. And I get

> moment has no default export.

when using `import moment from 'moment';` and setting `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`.

How do I properly install and use `momentjs`?

Comment: npm install @types/moment --save

Comment: @Nour When running that command it said `Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!`. So that's not it.

Comment: You can install moment.js as described in the docs and add link into .angular-cli.json but before using in your component, you will have to declare it.
E.g. declare let moment: any;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by importing `moment` with *(thanks to **@adejones**)*

```
import * as momentNs from 'moment';
const moment = momentNs;
```

which resulted in successful build. But I got an error

> moment is not a function

when using my library from another Angular 5 app. I solved that one by adding

```
"lib": {
    "externals": {
        "moment": "moment"
    }
}
```

to `ng-package.json` in my Angular 5 library and added

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "2.20.1"
}
```

to `package.json` of my Angular 5 app.

Answer (score 4):

try...

```
import * as moment_ from 'moment';
const moment = moment_;
```

see https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/221

Comment: Strangely that worked, thank you. :/ Gonna wait for a bit if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the common transform pipe method use:

```
import { DateFormatPipe } from "angular2-moment";
constructor(public dfp: DateFormatPipe) { }
var date = this.dfp.transform(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2608#issuecomment-170739817

As felix mentions here - for TypeScript use

```
import moment from 'moment/src/moment';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `momentjs` to your `package.json` depenencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    ...
}
```

You can then use moment as follows:

```
import * as moment from "moment";

export class DateThingy {

     public getDate(): moment.Moment { 
        return moment();
     }
}
```

---

**Extra import**

Or you can even make an extra import for the typing,

```
import { Moment } from 'moment'; // Import the moment typings
import * as moment from 'moment'; // Import the moment functions (and typings)
```

Which you can then use as:

```
export class DateThingy {
     public getDate(): Moment { 
        return moment();
     }
}
```

This is also explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171252/using-momentjs-with-typescript-what-type-does-moment-have/45215977#45215977)